# $cl(A)=bd(A) \cup A$ also $cl(A)=A^{'} \cup A$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $A$ be a subset of a metric space $(X,d)$.

We have the following two results about closure of a set,

$cl(A)=bd(A) \cup A$

$cl(A)=A^{'} \cup A$,

what is the relation between $bd(A)$ 
and $A^{'}$. Where $A^{'}$ is derived set of $A$.

Is $bd(A)=A^{'}$ or $bd(A) \subset A^{'}$ or $A^{'} \subset bd(A)$

Comment: Can you define $A'$? I have never heard "derived set" before.

Comment: yes. $A^{'}$ is the set of all limit points of $A$, you got it?

Comment: But these are precisely the points in $cl(A)$!?

Comment: $cl(A)$ is set containing all points and limit points of $A$

Answer (score 1):

There is no relation between $A'$ and $bd(A)$, consider the set $A = (0,1) \cup (1,2) \cup \{3\}$.

Comment: what is $bd(A)$ ?

Comment: You already used this notion in your question. It is the boundary of $A$.

Comment: i mean to say that calculate $bd(A)$ in your example

Comment: You should try to calculate this, it is not hard. This will help you to improve your understanding of this topic.

Comment: i thinks its empty set

Comment: if so, then this example doesnt support your claim

Comment: @gerw try different example

Comment: No, the boundary is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

bd(A) contained in A'.let x belongs to bd(A).then any open neighbourhood containing x must intersects both A and X-A.X is the whole space.Clearly x contains at least one element of A except x.Hence x is a limit point of A.  Take the open set (0,1) in usual metric space....the collection of limit point is [0,1].Here 0,1 are the only boundary points so A' may not contained in bd(A).

Comment: This is not true.

Comment: What did I miss?

Comment: Try $A = \{0\}$.